# Is the XCOM Enemy Within Commander Edition DLC on the disc?

Tags: xbox-360, xcom-enemy-within

A simple question for any Xbox players out there with Enemy Within - are the Slingshot and Elite Soldier DLC included on the disc, or is it a single-use download code?

I'm considering buying the game used for a friend.

Comment: It's a standalone disc.  You don't even need a copy of XCOM: EU.

Comment: Hey jason, if this is the answer? Shouldn't you have made it an answer and not a comment?

Comment: Was asking about Slingshot and the other DLC.  Know that EU is not required, just wondered how they implemented the DLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope! Its all included on the disc! Enemy within is bundled with slingshot and elite soldier, with no downloading required.

My sources are from [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/728010-xcom-enemy-within/67725879) and [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/review/R10T06GB0PJZMT/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00EM5UK5Y&nodeID=468642&store=videogames) of all places.